# How to access Picasa Albums from Android App

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, picasa, google-authentication

I am trying to access Picasa Albums using PicasawebService. This service requires authentication. How do I do this from an Android device, similar to what I have to do with Facebook Authentication?

What I mean is that Facebook SDK 4.x has a LoginManager, where I specify that I want to Login to my Facebook account with certain access privileges. If I am not currently logged in into my FB account, then FB login will show up, then it will ask me if I want to allow the user to access that was requested by the LoginManager.

On an Android device, I am already logged in, since I have to have a google account to have an Android device. Can someone point me to some sample code that will accomplish the above.

Thank You,